# Have any organisations or developers explored or currently working on a Hopin extension?

Tags: civievent, extension, civicrm-event

Our organisation is currently using Hopin to host events. I've searched whether there is an extension but haven't come across anything yet.

I would welcome to hear from anyone that has used this with Civi or currently exploring an extention.

Comment: I don't think there is any but if you are developer than you could develop one and share to contribute community. Its a nice extension to have.

Comment: Ditto - have never heard of this previously so expect it does not exist.

Comment: I have also not heard of it, I do not think it exists